# How to code condition for open price drops greater than a certain percentage

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to code a stochastic-based strategy and wanted to include a condition to close all positions if the price of the security drops by more than a certain percent from the open price.  Does anyone have an idea how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
X = input.float(50, "% drop") * 0.01

open_price = strategy.position_avg_price
is_valid_drop = low < (open_price * (1 - X))

if is_valid_drop
    strategy.close_all(comment = "Close ALL")
```